# In drupal 7 how to group fields of a view?

Tags: views

I have a view to display latest 10 blog pages.
1. I have a title field 
2. I have a author field

now I need to group all the titles in one div and all the author in another div.

But views results always have a nested result where respective node's title and author name are together in a same div. Is there any way to separate them?

Comment: You can write custom queries to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about  making two separate versions of the view: 1 page view with title fields and an attachement with author fields, or 1 page with titles, and the other a block with authors? 
So you first create a page view with a fields display. When adding fields, you select titles *and you make sure you set the field for "This page only".

[image]

Afterwards, on the top of the view, you select "add attachment"[image]. 
You will have an attachment versin of the view. In this, you add the "title" field. 
Again, make sure it's "for this attachment only". Now, go to "Attachment settings and select attach to page. 
[image]

Comment: The reason why I need two lists is that I have a plugin which on click of a title will display author name, so to execute this I need to structure the titles and author names in two different parent divs. Plus there are other similar functionality.

Comment: @AnAnD smells like jQuery to me..

Comment: is your structure like 
<div class="titles">
  <p>title1</p>
  <p>title2</p>
  ...
</div>

<div class="authors">
  <p>author1</p>
  <p>author2</p>
  ...
</div>
?

Comment: current structure is: <div class="row1"> 
<p>title1</p> 
<p>author1</p> 
</div> 
<div class="row2"> 
<p>title2</p> ... 
<p>author2</p> ... 
</div>

Comment: @Dalmaz I need it to be as you have mentioned above

Comment: @AnAnD I edited the answer to make it more complete

Comment: I fully agree the process for a static content. But it will not help in executing dynamic values. Where node Titles and Author names will be displayed based on taxonomy term.

Comment: Why not? That should work for dynamic (contexttual filter, I suppose) views as well, no?